# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo because of NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am a very beginner and I am making a small App with a List of different Japanese Temple. When you click on one of the Temple you should be able to take some notes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lvTempel = findViewById(R.id.lvSaigoku);
    List<String> saigokuList = createSaigokuList();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, saigokuList);
    lvTempel.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvTempel.setOnItemClickListener(new ListItemClickListener());
}

private List<String> createSaigokuList() {
    List<String> saigokuList = new ArrayList<>();
    saigokuList.add("第一番　青岸渡寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二番　金剛宝寺");
    saigokuList.add("第三番　粉河寺");
    saigokuList.add("第四番　施福寺");
    saigokuList.add("第五番　葛井寺");
    saigokuList.add("第六番　南法華寺");
    saigokuList.add("第七番　龍蓋寺");
    saigokuList.add("第八番　長谷寺");
    saigokuList.add("第九番　興福寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十番　三室戸寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十一番　醍醐寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十二番　正法寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十三番　石山寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十四番　園城寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十五番　観音寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十六番　清水寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十七番　六波羅蜜寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十八番　頂法寺");
    saigokuList.add("第十九番　行願寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十番　善峯寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十一番　穴太寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十二番　総持寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十三番　勝尾寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十四番　中山寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十五番　清水寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十六番　一乗寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十七番　圓教寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十八番　成相寺");
    saigokuList.add("第二十九番　松尾寺");
    saigokuList.add("第三十番　宝厳寺");
    saigokuList.add("第三十一番　長命寺");
    saigokuList.add("第三十二番　観音正寺");
    saigokuList.add("第三十三番　華厳寺");
    return saigokuList;
}

private class ListItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String tempelName = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), TempelEditActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("selectedTempleNo", position);
        intent.putExtra("selectedTempleName", tempelName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}




public class TempelEditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int _selectedTempleNo = 0;

private String _selectedTempelName = "";

private DatabaseHelper _helper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temple_edit);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    _selectedTempleNo = intent.getIntExtra("selectedTempleNo", 0);
    _selectedTempelName = intent.getStringExtra("selectedTempleName");

    _helper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    TextView tvTemple = findViewById(R.id.tvTempel);
    tvTemple.setText(_selectedTempelName);

    SQLiteDatabase db = _helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Tempel content = DataAccess.findContentByPK(db, _selectedTempleNo);
    EditText etHonzon = findViewById(R.id.tvHonzon);
    EditText etShushi = findViewById(R.id.tvShushi);
    EditText etAddress = findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
    EditText etUrl = findViewById(R.id.tvURL);
    EditText etNote = findViewById(R.id.tvNote);
    etHonzon.setText(content.getHonzon());
    etShushi.setText(content.getShushi());
    etAddress.setText(content.getAddress());
    etUrl.setText(content.getUrl());
    etNote.setText(content.getNote());
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    _helper.close();
}
```

}

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATANASE_NAME = "temple.db";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATANASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("CREATE TABLE temples (");
    sb.append("_id INTEGER,");
    sb.append("name TEXT NOT NULL,");
    sb.append("honzon TEXT,");
    sb.append("shushi TEXT,");
    sb.append("address TEXT,");
    sb.append("url TEXT,");
    sb.append("note TEXY");
    sb.append("PRIMARY KEY _id");
    sb.append(");");
    String sql = sb.toString();

    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

}

```
public class DataAccess {

public static Tempel findContentByPK(SQLiteDatabase db, int id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM temples WHERE _id = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    Tempel result = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int idxName = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        int idxHonzon = cursor.getColumnIndex("honzon");
        int idxShushi = cursor.getColumnIndex("shushi");
        int idxAddress = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        int idxUrl = cursor.getColumnIndex("url");
        int idxNote = cursor.getColumnIndex("note");
        String name = cursor.getString(idxName);
        String honzon = cursor.getString(idxHonzon);
        String shushi = cursor.getString(idxShushi);
        String address = cursor.getString(idxAddress);
        String url = cursor.getString(idxUrl);
        String note = cursor.getString(idxNote);

        result = new Tempel();
        result.set_id(id);
        result.setName(name);
        result.setHonzon(honzon);
        result.setShushi(shushi);
        result.setAddress(address);
        result.setUrl(url);
        result.setNote(note);
    }
    return result;
}

public static int update(SQLiteDatabase db, long id, String name, String honzon, String shushi, String address, String url, String note) {
    String sql = "UPDATE temples SET name = ?, honzon = ?, shushi = ?, address = ?, url = ?, note = ? WHERE id = ?";
    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
    stmt.bindString(1, name);
    stmt.bindString(2, honzon);
    stmt.bindString(3, shushi);
    stmt.bindString(4, address);
    stmt.bindString(5, url);
    stmt.bindString(6, note);
    stmt.bindLong(7, id);
    int result = stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
    return result;
}

public static long insert(SQLiteDatabase db, long id, String name, String honzon, String shushi, String address, String url, String note) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO temples (_id, name, honzon, shushi, address, url, note) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
    stmt.bindLong(1, id);
    stmt.bindString(2, name);
    stmt.bindString(3, honzon);
    stmt.bindString(4, shushi);
    stmt.bindString(5, address);
    stmt.bindString(6, url);
    stmt.bindString(7, note);
    long insertedId = stmt.executeInsert();
    return insertedId;
}

public static boolean findRowByPK(SQLiteDatabase db, long id) {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tempels WHERE _id = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    boolean result = false;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int idxCount = cursor.getColumnIndex("count");
        int count = cursor.getInt(idxCount);
        if (count >= 1) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

However, when I click on one of the list items, I get the following Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: local.hal.an25.android.saigoku33memo, PID: 27579
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{local.hal.an25.android.saigoku33memo/local.hal.an25.android.saigoku33memo.TempelEditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String local.hal.an25.android.saigoku33memo.Tempel.getHonzon()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String local.hal.an25.android.saigoku33memo.Tempel.getHonzon()' on a null object reference
    at local.hal.an25.android.saigoku33memo.TempelEditActivity.onCreate(TempelEditActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

As for a beginner, it's obvious that I get a NullPointeException because there is no data in the database, right? My question is now, how can I enter the activity to add some notes?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want enter to TempelEditActivity and insert to database note. Your content is null when you start activity, and you need add check this variable in TempelEditActivity method onCreate():

```
if (content != null) {
    etHonzon.setText(content.getHonzon());
    etShushi.setText(content.getShushi());
    etAddress.setText(content.getAddress());
    etUrl.setText(content.getUrl());
    etNote.setText(content.getNote());
}
```